# regular expression for last 4 digits of alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code to mask all but the the last 4 digits of a field, but when a user enters an alphanumeric in last 4 digits then it gives Null exception. Example input: `1a1a1a1a`

How could I accept characters as well?

```
var mask = val.match(/^(.*?)(\d{4})$/);

return (mask[1] ? mask[1].replace(/\d/g, '*') : '') + (mask[2] ? mask[2] : '')
```

The `return` line is giving an error: `Error: '1' is null or not an object`

Comment: Why do you need to use regex for this? If it's just string length based then just hide the last 4 characters no matter what they are?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I don't want to hide last 4. I want to show last 4 but mask remaining . for ex. 1a1a1a1a o/p ****1a1a

Comment: You can still do this with string length. I'll try to craft an answer for you.

Comment: if there are 3 digits or 4 digits then I want to mask only 1 st digit or char . ex 123 o/p *23

Comment: Do you want this to happen as the user types? Or is this just to hide some information in the database?

Comment: this should happen when user leaves the field

Comment: And if they re-enter the field? Do you wish to re-show them?

Comment: I liked your answer but is there any way to do with regular exp since I don't to change current logic and perform complete testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use regex for this. Just use string length functions.

Here's a jQuery solution:

```js
$(function() {
  var contents = "";
  $("#masking").blur(function() {
    contents = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(mask(contents));
  });
  $("#masking").focus(function() {
    if (contents.length > 0) {
      $(this).val(contents);
    }
  });
});

function mask(unmaskedValue) {
  if (unmaskedValue.length > 1) {
    var masked = "";
    var remain = 0;
    if (unmaskedValue.length <= 4) {
      masked += "*";
      remain = unmaskedValue.length - 1;
    } else {
      for (i = 0; i < unmaskedValue.length - 4; i++) {
        masked += "*";
      }
      remain = 4;
    }
    masked += unmaskedValue.substring(unmaskedValue.length - remain, unmaskedValue.length);
    return masked;
  } else
    return "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Type:</label>
<input id="masking" type="text">
```

Comment: I liked your answer but is there any way to do with regular exp since I don't to change current logic and perform complete testing

Comment: Simply put, regex should NOT be used for this kid of thing and the programmers convenience is not a valid reason to do it that way. You can however use this to return the mask rather than apply it directly by making it a function. This should allow you to preserve your logic. **See Update**